# Sharing gamefiles between players

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, server

I try to create a game that should help people learn for university. My problem is, how can player share questions between phones and also get them into the right folder. Is there a way for setting up a server to upload files and then download them? I had something in mind like the **Levelcode system** from "*Mario Maker*".

If a system like the one in "*Mario Maker*" would work, what kind of server do I need? I know I need some kind of a Database but do I need something like mySQL? And also how do I set it up? ***I never learned server programming, but I'm eager to learn.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up and host a [REST](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest) API.

There are many different ways to go about it, and it's really up to your preference for your host service, programming language, and a database library.

If you have no preference. I'd recommend:

[AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) - powerful and you get 12 months of free hosting

[Golang](https://golang.org/) - modern, fast, and great for web apps

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) ([go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)) - simple and lightweight

You will need to setup handlers for requests. So for example:

To add a new level:

```
POST example.com/level/
```

To get an existing level:

```
GET example.com/level/:id
```

In Golang you can handle a request using:

```
func levelHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
        // find level id in the database
    case "POST":
        // add level to database
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/level", levelHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil);
}
```

To modify an existing level:

```
PUT example.com/level/:id
```

The problem now is that anyone in the world will be able to change any level. You will want to add user authentication, and that's a whole other can of worms.

You may consider using [REST asset for Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/rest-client-for-unity-102501).

Just one final note: server programming is hard, be prepared to spend a lot of time trying, failing, and learning.